# What is the format of a Ravendbdump?

Tags: ravendb

Mongodb dumps are conveniently formatted as JSON. I was curious if a `ravendbdump` would be a binary or plaintext format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***.ravendbdump** is a binary gzipped file created when you export your database.

The exported file can later be imported to another database.

To view the **JSON** content of the *.ravendbdump file do the following:

1. rename file to *.gzip
2. extract file
3. open with notepad++

See the link: [How to export database from your client-api code](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/Csharp/client-api/smuggler/what-is-smuggler)

A database can also be exported through the **Studio** GUI application.
[http://live-test.ravendb.net/studio/index.html#databases/tasks/exportDatabase?&database=**Demo**.](http://live-test.ravendb.net/studio/index.html#databases/tasks/exportDatabase?&database=Demo)
**Note**: the link provided is to the specific 'Demo' database.

Any other database can be used if this one doesn't exist...